# Vertical align without using display:table-cell , needs to work IE6

Tags: html, css

Im trying to vertically align my links to the middle in a list

please see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TwFxN/

I cant use table-cell display or line-height as it needs to work in IE6 and line-height wont work as some options span 2 lines with a

Any Ideas?

Many thanks

Dave

Comment: Is there a problem with setting: `top: 25%;` in the links?

Comment: Don't forget to extra charge IE6 compatibility.

Comment: None of our jsFiddles display properly in Adobe Browserlab.

Comment: Top: 25% wouldn't work as they would all be same height from the top including the ones that span 2 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have IE6 access right now but try this:

```
#nav > li.rhombus {
    line-height: 5.0em;
}

#nav > li.rhombus a {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

This sets the `<li />` line height to match the height. Then reset the `<a />`'s line height.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/lnrb0b/TwFxN/2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to IE 6 but I think that this will work correctly:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/2fYLX/

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
 <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
 <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Listed<br> Securities</span></a></li>
 <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Market<br> Update</span></a></li>
 <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Membership</span></a></li>
 <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Info</span></a>
</ul>
```

​

CSS:

```
#nav a.rhlink:link, #nav a.rhlink:active, #nav a.rhlink:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 25%;
}

#nav > li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

#nav > li.rhombus {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: rgb(131,0,26);
    width: 8.3em;
    text-align: center;
    height: 5.0em;
    display: block;

}​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center each individual anchor tag within each li:

If you could set the height of the anchor tag to be a fixed number, then [the following](http://jsfiddle.net/TwFxN/18/) could work:

```
#nav a.rhlink:link, #nav a.rhlink:active, #nav a.rhlink:visited {
   display: block;
   padding: 0px 5px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: inherit;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   font-size: 12px;
   margin-top: -12px;
   text-align: center;
   width: 90%;
}
```

If you don't know the height of the list items, you might have to use javascript like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TwFxN/27/):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).css("top", Math.max(0, (($(this).parent().height() - $(this).outerHeight()) /      2)) + "px");
});
```

​

If you want to center the entire set of list items in the window:

If the height of the ul tag stays consistent, you could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TwFxN/6/):

```
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -5em;
}
```

If you want the navigation to wrap and still appear in the exact center, you might have to resort to using a little javascript like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TwFxN/7/):

```
$('#nav').css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $('#nav').outerHeight()) / 2) +              $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");​
```